# Magnific Popup Wordpress

Tags: magnific-popup

Magnific Popup Wordpress giving me a bit of a headache at the moment (3days) trying to open a php page called (**find.php**) in an iframe, which contains a form and other data off the same site from a button id is **ping**, it just will not happen for me.

In prettyPhoto on html5 easy to do, any help will save my brain, thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

The solution is you can change your WordPress plugin and install the "[WP Post Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-modal/)".
I hope you can easily solve your problem from here.